# Fail to grep by first character

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to list all files and select only certain from them.
`ls -1` return me the list

```
abc 
abcd
rm_0818-051752-753-06
```

after that I want to select only by this criteria to return the 3rd line so I do:

`ls -1 | grep -E "^rm_.*"`

but I get nothing.

I'm trying to recognize the first character of 3rd line in this way:

```
var=$(ls -1 | grep -E "rm_")
echo $var //returns rm_0818-051752-753-06
echo ${var:0:1} //returns some strange symbol 001B in square
```

Can you explain me this behavior and how could I grep by first character ^? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ls -1 | grep -E "^rm_.*"` looks good and should work. Possible reason why it doesn't work is alias bound to `ls` command in your profile.
To ensure, try 
`/bin/ls -1 | grep -E "^rm_.*"`

Comment: absolutely right!

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like you have `grep` aliased to `grep --color=always` or similar. You can check this by running `type grep`. I can reproduce a similar behavior:

```
$ var=$(ls -1 | grep --color=always "^rm")
$ echo ${var:0:1}
## Weird boxed character appears here
```

To see what's happening a bit better, we can pass `$var` through `od`:

```
$ echo "$var" | od -c
0000000 033   [   0   1   ;   3   1   m 033   [   K   r   m 033   [   m
0000020 033   [   K   _   0   8   1   8   -   0   5   1   7   5   2   -
0000040   7   5   3   -   0   6  \n
0000047
```

The `033   [   0   1   ;   3   1   m 033   [   K` are [ANSI color escapes](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php), and that's what's breaking here. You can avoid that by using an unaliased version of `grep`:

```
/bin/grep '^rm_'
```

or

```
\grep '^rm_'
```

Even better, don't parse `ls` since that often leads to [other problems](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). A safer and simpler way of doing what you want is:

```
$ var="rm*"
$ echo $var
rm_0818-051752-753-06
$ echo ${var:0:1}
r
```

Comment: absolutely right!

Comment: very useful information

Comment: In `var="rm*"` (or `var=rm*`), you're assigning `rm*` literally to `$var`, not `rm_0818-051752-753-06`. It's because you used the split+glob operator in the next line (`echo $var`), that you get `rm_0818-051752-753-06` there. The `echo ${var:0:1}` will extract the `r` from `rm*`, not `rm_0818-051752-753-06`

Answer (score 6):

Why grep, why not just:

```
ls -1 rm_*
```